# Significant figures on component's values

Tags: measurement

I'm reading a book where resistor values are discussed:

[image: This is the page from the book I was reading.]

I did not understand about how 3 significant figures can cover uncertainties from
1 to 0.1  % as stated in the 1st paragraph 6th line of the book.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: I'm not so sure it's off-topic. While it directly involves only math, it is a very important topic for electronics practitioners of all skill levels to understand when it comes to choosing components based on their characteristics.

Comment: tolerances are on-topic to electronics design.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty much self-explanatory.

"101 ohms" could be as far off as 100.5 ohms or 101.5 ohms 1/101 ~= 1%  **of nominal value**

"999 ohms" could be as far off as 998.5 ohms or 999.5 ohms 1/999 ~= 0.1% **of nominal value**

In other words the same number of ohms represents a much smaller percentage of the nominal value if the first (most significant) digit is an 8 or a 9 compared to if it is a 1 or a 2.

Comment: got it....I did not before catch the point that significant figure means that the last digit varies by 1...